# How to complete a link with user input

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, user-input

I'm completely new to javascript, and I'm trying to get a script to complete a link with a user input.

I.e. I have a common base url like `http://www.mystuff.com/` and I would like to create a form to let the user reach a specific page if he knows the exact url. I need a basic input field where he can write a string (like h5mlf4) that will send him clicking the submit button to `http://www.mystuff.com/h5mlf4`.

I've found this [script](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxz4R/1/) on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097573/is-it-possible-to-update-a-url-link-based-on-user-text-input) which is pretty close to my needs. I've tried to modify it, but I don't know how to do both the actions (add the user's input and launch the link) on the same button with an all-in-one action. I don't want to create the link on the page, I simply need it to be immediately used.

I hope to have been clear, and thanks to everybody will take care of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com?q=" + userInput;
```

to "click" that link (i.e. go to that link) for the user.

Doc for window.location >> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location