# How to open my UIImagePickerController on file input field in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I want to open my `UIImagePickerController` when user taps on file input field in `UIWebView`. Currently `UIWebView` opens its own `UIIMagePickerController` on which I don't have any control.

Comment: Add keyboard hide and show notification.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to change the url when the user taps on the file input field. There's an answer about doing something similar here: [Is it possible to update a url link based on user text input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097573/is-it-possible-to-update-a-url-link-based-on-user-text-input)

Then your `UIWebView` will need to catch that url change and open your `UIImagePickerController`. That can easily be done with this chunk of code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if ([URLString isEqualToString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/selectpic.htm"]) 
    {
        // Your UIImagePickerController code here
    }
    return YES;
}
```